# If rank($A$) + rank ($A-I$) $= n$, then $A$ is idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is a question posed in a linear algebra class:

> Let $A$ be a $n$ $\times$ $n$ matrix. Prove that if rank($A$) + rank ($A-I$) $= n$, then $A^2=A$.

Here is a possible attempt:
rank($A$) $=$ $n$ $-$ rank($A-I$) $=$ nullity ($A-I$)
column space($A$) $=$ null space($A-I$)
Let $x \in$ column space($A$) $=$ null space($A-I$)
Then, $x=Au$ and $(A-I)x = 0$
Thus $(A-I)(Au)=0$
Solving for $u$,
$(A-I)(A)=0$
so $A^2=A$.

However, this proof seems flawed.
For instance, rank($A$) $=$ nullity($A-I$) might not imply that column space($A$) $=$ null space($A-I$).

Moreover, I am not sure whether this statement is true. I see the converse statement being proven in many threads, but am unable to find a proof of this statement anywhere. Is this statement even true? Is it a typo?
Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any counterexamples so far.

Comment: Do you know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes. Are they involved? :o

Comment: It is one way to solve it. There are others too.

Comment: Oh, so the statement is true! Okay, I'll give it another try. Hints anyone? :3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true and the flawed proof that you've mentioned can be fixed. The key is to observe that $\ker(A)\cap\ker(A-I)=0$ and also that the given condition is equivalent to
$$
\operatorname{nullity}(A)+\operatorname{nullity}(A-I)=n.
$$
It follows that the whole vector space $V$ is equal to the direct sum of $\ker(A)$ and $\ker(A-I)$. Since $A^2=A$ on each of these two subspaces, the equality also holds on $V$.